# Can I Order Random results?

Tags: random

I want  to randomly pull out 3 records from a table and then order them to the field "sponsor_ranking".

My Code Reads.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM $TableSponsors ORDER BY RAND(), sponsor_ranking asc LIMIT 3";
```

But it is not ordering the results in order of the "sponsor_ranking" but it is randomizing the results.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, ordering by `sponsor_ranking` is only useful if each of the records had the same `RAND()` value, which is not so likely.

You can solve it like this. Order by random, limit to 3, order again by sponsor_ranking.

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM $TableSponsors 
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 3) x
ORDER BY
  sponsor_ranking
```

Answer (score 0):

you could make a subtable in the for clause :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM $TableSponsors ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) Faketable ORDER BY sponsor_ranking";
```

Answer (score 0):

This will never work. Doing an `order by` with multiple fields requires that the "earlier" fields have the same values for the second and subsequent fields to even be considered.

You'll have to use a subquery to do the rand() ordering, then rank by the other fields in the parent query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM $TableSponsors
    ORDER BY RAND()
) as foo
ORDER BY sponsor_ranking
LIMIT 3
```

e.g. if your table had this:

```
x  y
1  5
1  6
2  7
3  8
4  9

... ORDER BY x DESC, y ASC
```

then you'd get

```
x  y
4  9  // only one "4", so 9 is ignored, no point in sorting a single value
3  8  // only one "3", so 8 is ignored, no point in sorting a single value
2  7  // ditto
1  5  // hey, there's two "1" values, so now the second field **IS** sorted
1  6
```

Comment: I think this answer is wrong. ORDER BY RAND now doesn't do anything. You just order by `sponsor_ranking` and get the top 3.